# Vies database split address

Tags: api

I'm using vatlayer API for getting company information by put in the vat number. https://vatlayer.com/documentation

Now I want split address info in the state, zipcode, addressline and address number.

I get the address info: `BREDABAAN 13052900 SCHOTEN`. 
The address number and zipcode stands against each other without spacing. (1305number and 2900 zipcode).

Is there another API for working with the vies database where i can split these information? Or an work around for this bug?

VatLayer don't support the split atm.

I get the address information by:

```
$("#organisation_address_line_1").val(json.company_address);
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a lot of API's to handle VAT validation but the ones that provide information about the trader essentially all rely on the official API at http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl . It connects directly to the [VIES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VAT_Information_Exchange_System) system. Perhaps the values returned there are a bit different: it's worth trying your validation that way as well.

Unfortunately, since VIES does not return structured addresses (except for approximate matches, but only Spain supports them at the moment) and does not specify a common format for the free text addresses, you're going to have to deal with whatever format the country has chosen to provide, which means manual parsing.

I reckon 3rd party wrapping API's could handle guessing the format and splitting the formats on their own but I am not aware of any that would do it.